# Google Cloud Print

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-print

Up to and including yesterday, I was able to select to print a Google Sheet directly on my PC system (Linux Ubuntu 18.04) by selecting File → Print (or using the print icon).

Since today a new option has appeared:

[image]

and it only possible to complete the task (in my case) by selecting Print from my computer which represents an additional step in the print process.

Is there a way of suppressing this option as I have no wish to save my printed output to Google Drive nor connect my printer to Google or do anything other than just simply Print the document as I was able to before?

Comment: I've just tried this on my own laptop (Win10), and I don't get the Cloud Print options as they appear in your screenshot. In fact, it seems as though I need to add a "Classic" (attached) printer or a "Cloud Ready" printer in order for Cloud Print to be available. I notice that Cloud Print is in beta, has the "problem rectified itself or is it still happening?

Comment: @Tedinoz still there as at 31/8/20. Are you using a Linux or Windoze client?

Comment: I'm running on Win10

Comment: @Tedinoz maybe a «feature» of the Linux client then... There is an option in the print dialogue box to save to Google Drive so perhaps that is where it comes from.

Comment: Checked again today ... "Note: After 31 December 2020, Google Cloud Print will no longer be supported". Looks like is was a short lived feature.